# Why does Apache+mod_php on Windows require low RAM usage?

Tags: windows, apache, ram

I have Apache + mod_php installed on Windows but I can't relate it to any of those used on Linux.

It only has this:

```
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
```

regarding the children.

httpd.exe only takes 12MB of RAM and if I do an "ab" test with a script with only `sleep(10)` with 30 concurrent connections it only goes to 30MB of usage and it can take all of them together! I did the same on my ubuntu vps also in mod_php and to get 30 concurrent connections I had to start 30 servers and the VPS basically crashed because the RAM usage went over 200MB for the apache processes only. So the question is why the RAM used is -so- little?